Should we allow questions on using AI tools, e.g., how to phrase a prompt?
I recently looked at the question Generate illustrations without sharp rectangular boundary. The user is asking how to write a prompt for an AI to generate an image. While I did write an answer, part of me thinks that this type of question does not pertain to the expertise of a graphic designer. On the flipside, Adobe and I am sure other design programs are adding AI features to all of their programs.
There was a somewhat similar question on the meta stack exchange discussing using AI for answers: Are artificial intelligence answers permitted?. Should we allow questions asking how to use AI to design images, or how to use AI tools within design programs?
